# Como fazer operações entre arrays em python

Tags: python, array

Olá, estou aprendendo python, vi o básico e estou em um problema onde preciso fazer operações entre arrays. Tenho, por exemplo, dois arrays de iguais dimensão D. Para cada índice I nos array, quero fazer a diferença entre os dois i-ésimos elementos (um de cada array) e elevar ao quadrado, então passar para outro array no qual o produto terá mesmo índice I, para depois somar tudo, tirar a raiz quadrada e obter a distância euclidiana entre as coordenadas indicadas pelo array. O desafio é fazer isso sem utilizar loops. Alguém pode me dar uma luz? E agradeço se tiver um bom material sobre operações com arrays para indicar. Obrigado!

Comment: Por quê exatamente precisa fazer isso sem loops?

Comment: Recursividade seria considerado um loop nesse caso?

Comment: o módulo `numpy` tem métodos para arrays

Comment: @ClaytonTosatti claro. Em qualquer caso na verdade.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes:

Pelo que entendi, você tem dois listas (em Python, um vetor é chamado de lista):

```
x = [1, 5, 7]
y = [3, 6, 2]
```

A primeira parte do seu problema pode ser solucionada da seguinte forma:

```
z = [(v[0] - v[1]) ** 2 for v in zip(x, y)]
```

O que isto faz é criar um iterador contendo os elementos de cada vetor agrupados por índice `((1,3), (5,6), (7,2))`, depois fazemos a diferença de cada "grupo" `v[0]-v[1]`, elevamos ao quadrado e armazenamos em uma lista.

Neste caso, como são vetores com o mesmo número de elementos, a nova lista obviamente terá o mesmo número de elementos.

Agora vamos para o resto:

```
distancia = sum(z) ** (1 / 2.0)
```

Acredito que esta parte seja autoexplicativa.

É claro que isto tudo pode ser reduzido a uma linha mas particularmente acho um pouco ilegível:

```
distancia = sum((v[0] - v[1]) ** 2 for v in zip(x, y)) ** (1 / 2.0)
```

Ou utilizando lambda:

```
distancia = sum(map(lambda v: (v[0] - v[1]) ** 2, zip(x, y))) ** (1 / 2.0)
```